# Showing old them before new theme gets loaded for my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, caching

I have recently added an amp plugin to make my site responsive on the mobile front. Now when I load my site on mobile, I first see my old theme for a second and then automatically load with the latest theme. I tried clearing cache but didn't work. Hope I get any help here.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because the plugin you used is using the wp_is_mobile() function to change themes or the action is not hooked in at the right priority level for it to be executed before initial theme loading has started. Test a different plugin and see if that changes anything for you.